# How to set ordering list with Thai character list item type?

Tags: html, list, thai

I want to show below list itmes with thai character ordering -

```
ก. Lorem Ipsum dolor
ข. Lorem Ipsum dolor
ค. Lorem Ipsum dolor
```

I have tried with `list-style-type:thai;` but this is showing thai numbers in list.

```
<ol style="list-style-type:thai;">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
</ol>
```

Output: 
[image]

How can I generate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W3C has a [proposal](https://w3c.github.io/i18n-tests/results/custom-counter-styles#thai) on defining an additional value to `list-style-type`, `thai-alphabetic`. Unfortunately, it is not yet supported by popular browsers.

Nothing, however, prevents you from defining it in your documents:

CSS:

```css
@counter-style thai-alphabetic {
  system: alphabetic;
  symbols: "\E01" "\E02" "\E03" "\E04" "\E05" "\E06" "\E07" "\E08" "\E09" "\E0A";
  suffix: " ";
}

.items {
  list-style: thai-alphabetic;
}
```

Mind the [`system` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style/system) as it defines how numeric value is converted to your representation. In particular, example given above would render list item #11 as `กก.` while you may need the continuation throughout all available Thai consonants.

HTML:

```html
<ol class="items">
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>test2</li>
</ol>
```